# Prevent sequelize adding ending lowercase 's'

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I have this table defined as

```
var T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS = sequelize.define('T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS'
```

And I have configured it with this, to freeze the table name

```
    freezeTableName: true
```

And I use this table as an include query in another table like this

```
request.models.T_CPCORE_INGREDIENTS.findById(request.params.id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: request.models.T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS
    }
```

But if I print the object I get returned I can see in the console that the T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS now looks like this

```
T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITs
```

With a lowercase 's' at the end. And this is very annoying, because sometimes in my code where I use this name have to remember to use the lowercase 's'. 
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `alias` when defining association. If not, Sequelize automatically adds the unwanted `s` at the end of associated model name (in case of 1:m or n:m relations). Let's assume `hasMany` relation, just to show how it looks like

```js
T_CPCORE_INGREDIENTS.hasMany(T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS, { as: 'T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS' });
```

`alias` (`as`) defines [plural name of associated model](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#naming-strategy). Important thing when defining `alias` is to use it when eager loading models while querying

```js
request.models.T_CPCORE_INGREDIENTS.findById(
    request.params.id, {
    include: [
        {
            model: request.models.T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS,
            as: 'T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS'
        }
    }
)
```

So now, the model would have property `T_CPCORE_INGREDIENT_UNITS` as an array, without the added `s` at the end.

**Note:** alias can also be defined as object having properties `singular` and `plural`, which would define the naming strategy for single association or multiple associations.